# Quarkus OIDC and Expression Language for two roles in the @RolesAllowed annotation

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-oidc

I have a Quarkus 2.16 project with JDK 17.
I am trying to specify an array with 2 roles using Quarkus Expression Language, as shown in the snippet below:

```
@Path("/hello")
@RolesAllowed("${my-roles}")
public class GreetingResource {
    // ...
}
```

In the application.properties file, I have specified the property below with the two allowed roles:

```
my-roles=ROLE1,ROLE2
```

However, the application is not recognizing these roles.
Is there a way to specify an array of roles to be used with Expression Language in the @RolesAllowed annotation?

Are there alternatives?

Comment: There's no such thing as Quarkus Expression Language. The configuration engine used in Quarkus (SmallRye Config) supports expressions (https://smallrye.io/smallrye-config/Main/config/expressions/), but whether it's possible to use them in any given annotation is up to the particular Quarkus extension that handles the annotation. This is unfortunately not standardized across the Quarkus stack.